# Sorting a string lexicographically in c++

Tags: string, sorting, optimization

i am new in programming. i just learned strings in c++.

I have N strings and I want to sort them in lexicographical order.(Dictionary order)

How, can i do that as N is quite Big `1 <= N <= 1e5` and size of each string is `1 <= |s| <= 1000`.

Also the string is only made of small English alphabets.

I have figured out one method which is sorting them but test cases are tight and giving TLE.

Is there a better Approach for this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways.

1. Use `HASHING`.

***HOW TO USE ?***

- Create a simple integer array(hash[]) of size 26. Each of its index will denote an alphabet, considering your string is only comprised of small alphabets.
- Initialize the array to zero.
- Now traverse the string and for each occurred alphabet in string add its frequency by one in hash[]. For example if `'a'` occurred in string then `hash[0] = hash[0] + 1;`
- After you are finished with above step. you will have all characters frequency in hash.
- Now traverse your hash[] and for each index `i` print all characters until `hash[i]` becomes zero. It is because, as you want to sort string lexicographically the best way is `print all 'a' then all 'b' and so on present in string`.
- Time complexity for above method is `O(n*2s)`.
- Below is the program

```
int hash[26]={0};
for( int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++ ) // s.length() returns string length
{
   hash[s[i]-97] += 1; // s[i] - 97 actually returns index for the character
}
char ch;
for( int i = 0 ; i < 26 ; i++ )
{
   ch = i+97; // making the character required
   while(hash[i]) { cout << ch; hash[i] -= 1; } // printing it its frequency times
}
```

2. Use `nlog(n) sorting`

- In C++ you can use sort() function to sort the strings also.

***HOW ?***

- Just write `sort( s.begin() , s.end() ) ;`
- Complexity of this method is O(n*|s|log(|s|))
- Code is below

```
string s;
cin >> s;
sort( s.begin(); s.end() );
cout << s << endl;
```

Comment: thank you very much. i didn't knew we can use sort() in strings also. i was using O(n^2) sorting and getting TLE.

Comment: I used Both the ways and got All correct from both thank you very much for such good answer.

Comment: Have you started competitive programming ?

Comment: Yes i have just started.

Comment: Go to my blog post to know what is CP ? https://code-with-ease.blogspot.com/2020/04/what-is-competitive-programming.html hope it will help you.